# xCode : InfoPlist.strings localization files / xliff - not importing correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, info.plist

I had this reproducible problem:   (xCode 7.0 and 8.0, OS X El Capitan 10.11.6)

1) Add keys to the standard Info.plist file, for example: NSCameraUsageDescription, NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription, and NSHealthShareUsageDescription

2) Create an InfoPlist.strings localization file for translated warning strings for these keys (which in this case deal with once-shown Privacy setting dialogs).  Localize for English(United States), French, German etc.    You can verify that the translated strings for each language come up in the appropriate dialog at run-time.  i.e.:

```
/* NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription */
NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription = "myApp would like Bluetooth to connect to your device";
```

(I've tried NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription both with and without quotes.)

3) Add a reference to each used Key/String in some code somewhere so that you are able to export/import them.  e.g.:

```
NSString *strg = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"NSCameraUsageDescription", @"InfoPlist", @"NSCameraUsageDescription");
```

(I'm not sure this step is necessary.)

4) Using the Menu under Editor | Export for Localization...  export all your localizations to .xliff files.

5) Re-import the exact same .xliff files created in step 4, via Menu item under Editor | Import Localizations...

The strings within InfoPlist.strings disappear, even though they were properly exported!

Any idea what's wrong with this localization?  Is it a bug?  As far as I can tell this only happens with Info.plist localization.